# Set style to all TextView elements in a layout in one place

Tags: android, layout, styles

Is there a way to apply a style to all elements of a specific type in a layout xml without actually adding the style attribute to all of them?

I have a lot of TextView elements in a GridLayout. It would be nice if I could say that all TextView elements should have the style "CellFont" without actually having to put that statement into every single one of the TextView elements.

**Solution below:**

Added the GridLayoutCellFont style to style.xml and added that style as the android:theme to the Activity in the application manifest.

style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="GridLayoutCellFont">
        <item name="android:textSize">22dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/GridLayoutCellFont"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".TestLayoutsActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: could you share your some code?

Comment: Added the solution instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options you can either use Style or set new Theme read more at [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

set android style or theme.in raw can define the style